# Trouble sending javascript array to the same page via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I know this seems like already asked question, but I did research and none of the solutions worked for me. I have an `javascript array` like this:

```
[from: "2016-04-01", to: "2016-04-14"]
```

And I'm sending it via `AJAX` on the same page, like so:

```
data.date=date;
            console.log(data.date);
            $.ajax({
                url: "",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: data,
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {

                }
});
```

And I put `var_dump($_POST['date']);` at the beginning of my page. When I look at `Network` took of my browser I can see that request is sent, and my page is listed within Network pages, but `$_POST['date']` array is `NULL`. And I did put this `JS` code within `$(document).ready();`, so that cannot be the issue. I just want to get value of this `javascript array` into `php` variable.

Comment: Try to pass `JSON.stringify(data)` to the `data` param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be [{from: "2016-04-01", to: "2016-04-14"}] ? Isn't it an object inside the array?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I made mistake by declaring `var data=new Array()` instead of `var data={};`